# user can not access to authorized controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I created user login page. when i click the submit button, everything is okay.
I mean this methods is succeeded when i click the submit button:

- The User's userName and password find successfully on database.
- Redirects are successful

But at last the user can not access to defined controllers.

---

*This is my identity ApplicationUser model:*

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

---

*This is my Login view model that uses `ApplicationUser` model:*

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "AN ERROR")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "AN ERROR")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "AN ERROR")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

---

*This is my view for users login:*

```
@model WOWapplication.Models.ViewModels.LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@addTagHelper * , Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper * , WarOfWords


        <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post" asp-route-returnUrl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]">
            <input asp-for="UserName" type="text"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="UserName"></span>
            <input asp-for="Password" type="password"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
            <div>
                <input asp-for="RememberMe" type="checkbox" />
                <label asp-for="RememberMe"></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">ورود</button>
                <button asp-controller="Register" asp-action="Register">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

---

*And finally this is the controller that handles the above codes:*

```
namespace WOWapplication.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _SignInManager;
        public AccountController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _SignInManager = signInManager;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost] 
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectTolLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Wrong User name or password");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        private IActionResult RedirectTolLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

In addition i use `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` for the actions that i want Admin accesses to that controller.

Please help me find the error in my project. Because this problem has no errors and everything is done right but finally Login can not be successfully completed and the Admin user does not have permission. Remember that everything in the controller is successful. Thank you all.

Comment: Are you sure that Role of user inserted in `AspNetUserRoles` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is correct. Follow bottom :

- Check `AspNetRoles` and sure that there are `Rolse` in table
- And Check `AspNetUserRoles` and sure that Role of user inserted correctly

If Roles and UserRoles inserted correct, get Role of user in `Login` action by below code :

```
var userRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.ToArray();
```

**OR**

```
var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

I put complete Login Code here :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName,
                model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //Success Login
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
                var userRole = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

           }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

**My issue was solved by putting `app.UseAuthentication();` in `Configure()` method in startup.cs**